# Bridge interface does not get IP address after reboot

Tags: networking, reboot

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.
I'm using kvm and added a bridge interface to be able to connect from VM to outside internet.
These are the steps I followed to do that.

```
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
dhclient br0
```

And edited /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
 bridge_ports eth0
 bridge_stp on
 bridge_fd 0
 bridge_maxwait 0
```

Now I had to edit this file because, without that, my vm manager does not recognize br0 interface.

Now the problem is, if I reboot my machine with these changes intact, it throws a message, "Waiting for network configuration"  and takes a long time to boot.

And after coming up, none of the interfaces have IP adresses, and I dont see the network button on the top-left corner of my desktop. But thing is, br0 interface gets IP address after a while (sometimes) without my intervention.
I'm completely confused. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I have been trying to solve this for days, now I find a solution after posting the question. Removing eth0 entry from /etc/network/interfaces solved the problem. Reboot takes normal amount of time and network connectivity is up as well. I would still like an explanation though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0` is basically "use DHCP", whereas `iface eth0 inet manual` is "use static IP" (but none is set).  Both are mutually exclusive, so removing the latter solved your problem.

Comment: A short and effective answer =)